# Crashlytics plugin not uploading mapping file

Tags: android, crashlytics, android-instant-apps

I've refactored my project separating functionality into library modules in order to support Instant Apps. Everthing works great but I'm not able to see the deobfuscated stack trace at Crashlytics's issue detail of my installed application like I was seeing before. I'm using the Fabric gradle plugin v1.24.5 and I have the following line in the base module gradle file:

`apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'`

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @Alexizamerican, I found the Crashlytics log at "~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/" and there isn't any reference to the mapping file:

```
2017-11-28 09:30:47.855 [DEBUG] (Task worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - Invoked Crashlytics Developer Tools with arguments: 
-injectableManifest true
-androidBaseManifest /Users/sirkuryaki/AndroidStudioProjects/Yop/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
-buildEvent true
-androidManifest /Users/sirkuryaki/AndroidStudioProjects/Yop/app/build/intermediates/manifests/aapt/prod/release/AndroidManifest.xml
-apiSecret **XXX**
-generateResourceFile true
-tool io.fabric.tools.gradle
-version 1.24.5
-properties /Users/sirkuryaki/AndroidStudioProjects/Yop/app/crashlytics.properties
-twitterPluginId **XXX**
-buildId **XXX**
-targetResValueDir /Users/sirkuryaki/AndroidStudioProjects/Yop/app/build/generated/fabric/res/prod/release
-projectPath /Users/sirkuryaki/AndroidStudioProjects/Yop/app
-androidRes /Users/sirkuryaki/AndroidStudioProjects/Yop/app/src/main/res
-androidAssets /Users/sirkuryaki/AndroidStudioProjects/Yop/app/build/intermediates/bundles/prodRelease/assets
2017-11-28 09:30:47.939 [DEBUG] (Task worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - apiKey is **XXX**
2017-11-28 09:30:47.997 [DEBUG] (Task worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - Generating crashlytics resources
2017-11-28 09:30:47.998 [DEBUG] (Task worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - Generating build info into assets folder: /Users/sirkuryaki/AndroidStudioProjects/Yop/app/build/intermediates/bundles/prodRelease/assets
2017-11-28 09:30:48.001 [DEBUG] (Task worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - Updating build properties at: /Users/sirkuryaki/AndroidStudioProjects/Yop/app/build/intermediates/bundles/prodRelease/assets/crashlytics-build.properties
2017-11-28 09:30:48.004 [DEBUG] (Task worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - Set build id to **XXX**
2017-11-28 09:30:48.014 [DEBUG] (Build Event Notification) com.crashlytics  - Build Event: **XXX** ID:**XXX** ApiKey:**XXX** Tool:io.fabric.tools.gradle 1.24.5 Base Package Name:com.yopapp.yop Twitter Client Application Id:**XXX** API Secret Null? false Extra Details:[null]
2017-11-28 09:30:49.982 [DEBUG] (Build Event Notification) com.crashlytics  - REQUEST: https://api.crashlytics.com/spi/v1/platforms/android/apps/com.yopapp.yop/built
2017-11-28 09:30:56.789 [DEBUG] (Build Event Notification) com.crashlytics  - POST response: [reqId=**XXX**] 200
```

But if I look at previous builds I can see the following lines:

```
-storeDeobs /Users/sirkuryaki/AndroidStudioProjects/Yop/app/build/outputs/mapping/prod/release/mapping.txt
2017-10-02 13:14:45.416 [DEBUG] (Daemon worker Thread 4) com.crashlytics  - Caching deobfuscation file
2017-10-02 13:14:45.417 [DEBUG] (Daemon worker Thread 4) com.crashlytics  - Saving deobfuscation file: /Users/sirkuryaki/AndroidStudioProjects/Yop/app/build/outputs/mapping/prod/release/mapping.txt
2017-10-02 13:14:45.417 [DEBUG] (Daemon worker Thread 4) com.crashlytics  - Crashlytics is caching deobs file at /Users/sirkuryaki/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/app-**XXX**/deobs/**XXX**zip
```

Comment: Have you tested, it was working properly?. please have a look it might help you. https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/settings/removing.html

Comment: @PragatiSingh it was working before and works with other projects.

Comment: @ArielCarbonaro have you found the solution? I also face the same issue, I cannot find reference of mapping file in my crashlytics.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the root cause, if you are using Gradle plugin 3.0+, the fabric plugin may not be able to upload automatically. They are releasing new version(ver. 1.24.0) that has fixed this issue. You can check the release log [here](https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#august-9-2017)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Set Up a Library Subproject](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html?highlight=library#set-up-a-library-subproject) 
    for library setup instructions.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I implemented it but it doesn't look like a dependency issue because it's compiling and sending reports. The only thing that isn't working are the deofuscated methods names.

Comment: Are you using Kotlin by chance? Also, if you look at crashlytics.log (on Linux /Windows:~/.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log and . on Mac:~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log) do you see a referent to uploading the mapping.txt file?

Comment: no, its only JAVA code. But I've updated my question with the log info

Comment: I'll need to see if your build.gradle files to understand your configuration. Can you share them here? If not, if you write into Fabric support with your build.gradle files. the team can take a closer look.

Comment: Yes sure! Jus't let me know when I can delete the gist https://gist.github.com/SirKuryaki/25e0ab35246f997428a962982c517639

Comment: Hmm it doesn't look like you're using Proguard or Dexguard. Can you share a link to an obfuscated crash?

Comment: Proguard is enabled in the application's gradle. I've updated the gist with the installed gradle file